# How will using leaves as toilet paper affect the composting of my toilet?

Tags: composting, toilet

My bathroom is surrounded by a fuzzy leafed species, planted specifically for this purpose, I imagine.  Many people I talk to around here can still vividly remember before toilet paper.  I have yet to fully switch over, but I am considering it, and am wondering about the implications for my composting toilet.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the types of leaves you want to use?

Comment: @orschiro will get a picture up as soon as possible, its harder than you think to remember to bring the camera to the bathroom!

Comment: @THelper That sounds like a great answer!  Perhaps with a couple of recommendations of what I should throw in there - more sawdust?

Comment: I'm confused. You were asking about the toilet, now it's the bathroom. Are you using these leaves instead of a towel after a bath?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the toilet is in the 'bathroom', although I do use a towel and I am talking about the toilet.  It used to be a water toilet and we converted it, I guess as a prototype.  Any new dry toilet will be separated from the shower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only difference of using leaves compared to toilet paper is that you'll be adding more nitrogen to the mix. This means that your C:N ratio will change, but you can solve this easily by adding more browns (carbon).

Some examples of good browns are straw, cardboard or sawdust. You can check the [table in this answer](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/1280/99) to see the C:N ratio of some common household wastes and see what else you can use. Higher numbers mean more carbon.